# How to properly set log level to verbose in Google Analytics?

Tags: android, logging, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

In folder `res/xml`, I have the file `analytics.xml` containing this line:

```
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
```

However, in the `onCreate()` method of my `Activity`, when I call this:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(R.xml.analytics);
Log.d("abc",""+(GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().getLogLevel() == Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE));
```

The output is false, not true. So why is that?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
```